# TypeError: _this.props.loginState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When the user presses the login button the Drawer.Navigation needs to change (I try to learn the basics so no form for the login needed). When I try to pass this action to App.js I get this Error:"TypeError: _this.props.loginState is not a function"

According to the errormessage the problem should be in this pice of code:

```
    changeLoginState = () => {
        this.props.loginState(true)
    }
```

This is the code of App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute, NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { RootNavigator } from './src/navigation/AppNavigator';
import { PropTypes } from 'react'

//navigation
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import Account from './src/screens/account';
import Login from './src/screens/Login'

export default function App(){

    let isLoggedIn = false

    function changeLoginState(newState){
        isLoggedIn = newState
    }
        
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

        let d
        let p
        let l

        if(isLoggedIn){
            d = <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={Account}/>
        }else{
            d = <Drawer.Screen name="Inloggen" component={Login} loginState={changeLoginState}/>
        }

        return(
            <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
              {d}
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
}
```

And this is the code of Login comoponent: Login.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    changeLoginState = () => {
        this.props.loginState(true)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', height: '100vh'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} onPress={ () => this.changeLoginState() }>Login</TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Login
```

I have seen a lot of similar questions but nothing worked.
If you have other remarks on my code, feel free to comment.

I thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `options` to pass props to screen:

```
options={{ loginState: changeLoginState }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. For the record: this does not solve my problem. Right?

Comment: Still the same problem. I edited the question where the problem is according to my browser.

Comment: Are you sure pass `options` to `<Drawer.Screen />`

Comment: Like this right? ```<Drawer.Screen name="Inloggen" component={Login} options={{loginState: changeLoginState}}/>```

Comment: Yes. But I changed ```this.props.loginState()``` to ```this.props.loginState```  and the error is gone now the receiving  function is not executed.

Comment: why you change it?

Comment: You must call `loginState()`

Comment: why you change it?